# Config files in Datastage

Tags: datastage

We can have multiple config files in a project. Even we can run a parallel job on different config files. But can we run a parallel job on multiple config files at a time or can a parallel job use multiple config files at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

One job will use one configuration file but you can limit ressources for certain stages by running them on certain nodes(node pools).
Check out node pool and resource constraints located at the Advanced tab of the stages.

This means you can prepare a config file to support multiple scenarios and multiple levels of parallelism.